# Scale tikzpicture with axis and xbar to the "real" textwidth

Tags: pgfplots, width, textwidth

So, whenever I create a xbar plot with long labels it happens to me that the tikzpicture is scaled too wide because (I guess) `textwidth` only applies to the axis but not the labels. So I thought I substract the width of the longest label from textwidth, but then the width is too small. My question is:

1. how can I get the "real" textwidth?
2. if possible, how can I get that automatically without entering the longest label by hand

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents*}{species.dat}
species,no_dbh
Fagus sylvatica,0.746478873239437
Pinus sylvestris,0.633802816901408
Quercus petraea,0.563380281690141
Pseudotsuga menziesii,0.126760563380282
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{figure}[hpbt] 
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{species.dat}{\steigi}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            x tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
            y tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
            height=5cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            major grid style={dotted, very thick},
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=none,
            bar width=5pt,
            symbolic y coords={Fagus sylvatica,Pinus sylvestris,Quercus petraea,Pseudotsuga menziesii},
            ytick=data,
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100} pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            y dir=reverse,
            enlarge y limits=0.2,
            xmax=0.85,
            xmin=0,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west,font=\scriptsize},
            nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            point meta=x*100,
            nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%
            ]             
            \addplot[fill=gray]  table [x=no_dbh,y=species]{\steigi};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Tree species probability}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]
\end{document}
```

My solution is too use `width=\textwidth-width("Pseudotsuga menziesii")` but then it's scalled too small.

Comment: How's it too wide? I tried to compile your code but did not get the "too wide" point.

Comment: @L.F. I am sorry, I implemented my solution which makes it too small. I removed it.

Comment: OK. But I think the result is ok with `width=\textwidth-width("Pseudotsuga menziesii")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting the largest label and measure its width with the correct font settings, you can first typeset the whole diagram in a savebox and then calculate the requires axes width to get the complete graph `\textwidth` wide. Then typeset it again with that width setting. This has the drawback that the computation effort is doubled, but this should not be a problem on modern computers, but only on very large documents.

Very large diagram code might be better places into an own TEX file and read using `\input`, otherwise the argument to `\adjustwidth` will need a lot of memory.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents*}{species.dat}
species,no_dbh
Fagus sylvatica,0.746478873239437
Pinus sylvestris,0.633802816901408
Quercus petraea,0.563380281690141
Pseudotsuga menziesii,0.126760563380282
\end{filecontents*}

\newlength\WIDTH
\newbox\mybox

\newcommand\adjustwidth[1]{%
    \setlength\WIDTH{\textwidth}
    \savebox\mybox{#1}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\WIDTH{2\textwidth-\wd\mybox}
    #1%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{figure}[hpbt] 
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{species.dat}{\steigi}
    \centering
    \adjustwidth{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            x tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
            y tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
            height=5cm,
            width=\WIDTH,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            major grid style={dotted, very thick},
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=none,
            bar width=5pt,
            symbolic y coords={Fagus sylvatica,Pinus sylvestris,Quercus petraea,Pseudotsuga menziesii},
            ytick=data,
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            y dir=reverse,
            enlarge y limits=0.2,
            xmax=0.85,
            xmin=0,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west,font=\scriptsize},
            nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            point meta=x*100,
            nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%
            ]             
            \addplot[fill=gray]  table [x=no_dbh,y=species]{\steigi};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{Tree species probability}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]